# What comes first here? pemdas doesnt really tell me what to do here

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

So I have this equation:
$2x(x+3)(x+3)$

Do I FOIL the $(x+3)$ first or multiply the $2x$ to the first $(x+3)$? Would there be a difference? Isn't multiplication commutative?

Comment: Because multiplication is commutative, it doesn't matter in which order you multiply out the terms. I suggest trying both ways and then learning from that which you find the more elegant.

Comment: Please use correct English. Capitalize "I" and the first letter of each sentence. Also see here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help typing equations. To answer you question, it doesn't matter what order.

Comment: @SimonS: the important property here is that multiplication is associative.  It happens to be commutative, too, but that is not the issue.

Comment: Pretend that the $x$ is a $5$. Furthermore, pretend that your calculator is broken; it won't add a $3$ to a $5$.

How would you evaluate $2\cdot 5(5+3)(5+3)$ on this calculator? Can you evaluate the expression in more than one way?

Comment: @RossMillikan You're quite right. I misspoke

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is associative. That is, $a \cdot b \cdot c= (a \cdot b)\cdot c.$

So, for $2x(x+3)(x+3)$, we can find $2x(x+3)$ and multiply that by $(x+3).$

Elaborating further, we have $2x(x+3)(x+3)=(2x^2+6x)(x+3)=2x^3+12x^2+18x$

Furthermore, we could use PEMDAS here. There are no parentheses or exponents, so we simply multiply from left to right, the same way you would evaluate $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4.$

Answer (score 1):

The **expression** $$2x(x+3)(x+3)$$ (its not an equation) can be expanded in a variety of ways. Perhaps the easiest is: $$2x(x+3)(x+3) = 2x(x+3)^2 = 2x(x^2+6x+9) = 2x^3+12x^2+18x$$

Whatever method you prefer is just fine, so long as it adheres to the laws of arithmetic.

Comment: I believe the coefficient on $x$ should be $18$.

Comment: @zz20s, thanks!

Comment: No problem. +1 for noting that we're dealing with an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is associative.  Hence, $(ab)c = a(bc)$.  Therefore, the order in which the terms in the expression are multiplied does not matter.

To illustrate this observation with the product $2x(x + 3)(x + 3)$, we will show that first multiplying the first two terms of the expression, then multiplying the result by the third term yields the same result as first multiplying the last two terms of the expression, then multiplying the result by the first term. 
\begin{align*}
2x(x + 3)(x + 3) & = [2x(x + 3)](x + 3)\\
                 & = (2x^2 + 6x)(x + 3)\\
                 & = 2x^2(x + 3) + 6x(x + 3)\\
                 & = 2x^3 + 6x^2 + 6x^2 + 18x\\
                 & = 2x^3 + 12x^2 + 18x
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
2x(x + 3)(x + 3) & = 2x[(x + 3)(x + 3)]\\
                 & = 2x[x(x + 3) + 3(x + 3)]\\
                 & = 2x(x^2 + 3x + 3x + 9)\\
                 & = 2x(x^2 + 6x + 9)\\
                 & = 2x^3 + 12x^2 + 18x
\end{align*}

Note that $2x(x + 3)(x + 3)$ is an algebraic *expression*, not an equation.  The *equation* $2x(x + 3)(x + 3) = 2x^3 + 12x^2 + 18x$ asserts that the algebraic expressions $2x(x + 3)(x + 3)$ and $2x^3 + 12x^2 + 18x$ are equivalent.